# How to use Micronaut's RxStreamingHttpClient

Tags: java, micronaut-client

I'm trying to use RxStreamingHttpClient in my controller to stream 100MB file but Micronaut (v3.10.1) logs an error after starting the transfer:

```
16:13:20.287 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] WARN  io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil - Failed to release a message: PooledSlicedByteBuf(freed)
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
        at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.toLiveRealRefCnt(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:83)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.release(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:148)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:101)
        at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(ReferenceCountUtil.java:90)
        at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.safeRelease(ReferenceCountUtil.java:116)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:282)
```

and curl's output:

```
nwer@alpha ~/tmp $ curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/binary/test1' -i -o test
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12489    0 12489    0     0   8642      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  8678
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

Below is a method in my controller:

```
@Get(value = "/test1", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    Flowable<ByteBuffer<?>> test1() throws MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8085");
    HttpClientConfiguration conf = new DefaultHttpClientConfiguration();
    conf.setMaxContentLength(2147483647);
    RxStreamingHttpClient client = RxStreamingHttpClient.create(url, conf);
    return client.dataStream(HttpRequest.GET("/v1/objects/9e3aad86-491c-451c-afbc-98f8c21a6ab8/100MbFile"));
    }
```

What is missing in my implementation? Is this the best way to stream ~100MB files via Micronaut?